# Python Django Beginner: can't open manage.py

Tags: python, django

Trying to get started with Django on pycharm.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Vince\PycharmProjects\assignment>python manage.py runserver
```

But I get this error message whenever i run manage.py:

> C:\Users\Vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I do have a django directory opened with a manage.py file in it. Can anyone assist me on what to do?

I have tried other solutions, like:

```
python -vvvvv manage.py runserver
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either specify the exact location of the `manage.py` file. I.e.:

`python3 Users/Vince/Desktop/DjangoProject/manage.py runserver`

or `cd` to the directory it's in and run from there.

`cd Users/Vince/Desktop/DjangoProject` > `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @AsuruVincent if so, please mark this answer as accepter.